# Is there a solution to this VxWorks C++ demangling error?

Tags: vxworks

I am attempting to compile a simple C++ downloadable object module to be run on [VxWorks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VxWorks) 6.8. I am following the instructions [here](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/guide/c-wfc.html). I am getting an error. How can I fix it?

```c
#include <vxworks.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int helloworld()
{
    printf("Hello, World!!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

I run the following build commands as instructed in the aforementioned link

#### 1. Compile

> `C:/WindRiver/gnu/4.1.2-vxworks-6.8/x86-win32/bin/ccpentium.exe -o tester.o  -march=pentium -fno-builtin -DINCLUDE_CPLUS -DINCLUDE_CPLUS_LANG -DINCLUDE_CPLUS_DEMANGLER -DINCLUDE_CPLUS_IOSTREAMS -DTOOL=gnu -DCPU=PENTIUM -D_VSB_CONFIG_FILE=\"C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/lib/h/config/vsbConfig.h\" -I. -I$(WIND_BASE)/target/h -I$(WIND_BASE)/target/h/make/rules.library -I$(WIND_BASE)/target/h/wrn/coreip -c tester.cpp`

#### 2. Run munch

> `C:\WindRiver\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin\nmpentium.exe tester.o | wtxtcl C:\WindRiver\vxworks-6.8\host\resource\hutils\tcl\munch.tcl -c pentium > ctdt.c`

#### 3. Compile ctdt.c file generated by *munch*

> `C:/WindRiver/gnu/4.1.2-vxworks-6.8/x86-win32/bin/ccpentium.exe -march=pentium  -fdollars-in-identifiers -O2 -fno-builtin -I"C:\WindRiver\vxworks-6.8\target\h" -DINCLUDE_CPLUS -DINCLUDE_CPLUS_LANG -DINCLUDE_CPLUS_DEMANGLER -DINCLUDE_CPLUS_IOSTREAMS -DCPU=PENTIUM -DTOOL_FAMILY=gnu -DTOOL=gnu  -c ctdt.c`

#### Error

However, whenever compiling *ctdt.c*, I get the following error(s):

```
ctdt.c: In function '_STI__15_ctors':
ctdt.c:20: error: stray '\10' in program
ctdt.c:20: error: flexible array member in otherwise empty struct
```

The line of code *ctdt.c* that is throwing the error looks like this. Note, I had to include it as an image because there is a strange character in the code that I could not figure out how to display here:

[Code throwing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vP52.jpg)

I believe the error has something to do with the " in the *printf* statement. Commenting out the *printf* statement everything will compile file.

Comment: Please post your solution as an *answer* an accept it. This will mark the question as solved.

Comment: Re *"had to include it as an image"*: One thing does not exclude the other. Please post the code as is. There is crucial information in there. Even if it can't be displayed, it can still be analysed, e.g., by making a hex dump.

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*

Comment: \10 (most likely octal) = 8 (decimal) = 0x8 (hexadecimal). [ASCII 0x8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart) is Backspace, AKA Ctrl + H and C escape sequence '`\b`'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. The munch step above is incorrect and should be: C:\WindRiver\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin\nmpentium.exe tester.o | tclsh C:\WindRiver\vxworks-6.8\host\resource\hutils\tcl\munch.tcl -c pentium > ctdt.c